# Литература по C++ для бывшего Дельфийца

Tags: c++, delphi

Возможно, есть сравнительные статьи, то есть "так на делфи, а так это выглядит на C++".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не совсем в тему, но может быть полезно: [C# for Delphi Developers](http://www.glennstephens.com.au/tech/CSharp4DelphiDevelopers.pdf). А вот еще в догонку: [Comparing Object-Oriented Features of Delphi, C++, C# and Java](http://www.derangedcoder.net/programming/general/comparingObjectOrientedFeatures.html).

Answer (score 0):

Если не боитесь толстых килограммовых книг - [Бьерн Страуструп "Язык программирования С++"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/5600302/).

Answer (score 0):

90% книг по программированию, которые я читал (Delphi), содержали листинги на си и делфи, или я такие спецефичные вещи читаю. оО)

Answer (score -1):

Мне очень понравилась вот эта книга: [Философия С++. Введение в стандартный С++](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1631049/), правда я её читал после "Языка программирования C"  Кернигана и Ритчи и когда уже писал кое-что по мелочи на C++Builder.